# jq not showing all the results

Tags: jq

I have the following json:

```
[
  {
    "_source": {
      "layers": {
        "http2": {
          "http2.stream": {
            "http2.length": "1030"
          }
        },
        "http2": {
          "http2.stream": {
            "http2.length": "1246"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I am doing the following `jq` command:

```
jq '.[]._source.layers.http2."http2.stream"' file.json
```

I am expecting to get the following result:

```
{
  "http2.length": "1030"
}
{
  "http2.length": "1246"
}
```

But I am only getting:

```
{
  "http2.length": "1246"
}
```

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/ tells me this is an invalid JSON because 'http2' appears twice as a key.

Comment: You might want to make `layers` an array not an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jq behaves as reasonably as possible here, expecting JSON as input. JSON dictionaries are *unique* key-value mappings, and your key`"http2"` appears twice.

So, you're requesting a lookup on a duplicate key, and that successfully gets you the last value specified for it, tolerating invalid input as well as possible.